# How to change the data source of an Excel Pivot Chart?

Tags: excel, pivot-chart

I'm trying to reuse an Excel Pivot Chart to make similar charts from others Pivot Tables.
Suppose I make a `Pivot Chart A` from a `Pivot Table A` and customize its colours and formats.  After that, suppose I need to make a second `Pivot Chart B` from a `Pivot Table B` with the same characteristics from `Pivot Chart A`.  As suggest by [@teylyn](https://superuser.com/questions/822044/is-it-possible-to-make-a-pivot-chart-a-subset-of-pivot-table) and [@Jon Peltier](https://superuser.com/questions/815798/have-pivot-chart-show-only-some-columns-in-pivot-table) in their answers, I made different Pivot Tables from the same dataset to do each Pivot Chart.

- Example dataset

```
blood   height  weight
A       58      115
A       59      117
B       60      120
AB      61      123
O       62      126
A       63      129
AB      64      132
B       65      135
O       66      139
AB      67      142
A       68      146
B       69      150
AB      70      154
AB      71      159
B       72      164
```

- Pivot Tables

[image: Pivot Tables]

- Pivot Chart A

[image: Pivot Chart A]

Now suppose I want to recycle this `Pivot Chart A` copying, pasting and changing its datasource (initially `Pivot Table A`) to the `Pivot Table B`. But when I  right click into the copied chart and selecting the option `Select datasource`the data range is locked and I can't change its reference cells to the `Pivot Table B`.

So, is there a way to change the datasource from the copy of the Pivot chart A  to the Pivot Table B? 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: I *think* you will need to change the pivot table source, not the chart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To change the data source of a pivot chart, you will have to break the link between the chart and the pivot table. How you can do this is described in the below link:

https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/2710-excel-pivot-chart-change-data-source-legends.html